# Show Bootstrap-modal window when user clicks on <option> in <select>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to display a large bootstrap modal when user clicks on one of the options showed in a Select tag (designed with Bootstrap too)

```html
<select name="choice" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" style="overflow:visible;">
 <optgroup label="Please make a choice">
   <option value="1" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">1st choice</option>
   <option value="2" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">2nd choice</option>
   <option value="3" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">3rd choice</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>




   <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
```

It doesn't show anything though. I can't do that within the Option tag or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the selectpicker plugin?

Comment: Yes i'm using bootstrap-select.js. It's where the conflict comes from, I noticed if I erase  class="selectpicker" from the Select tag it works but then my select form is screwed. I still haven't understand how to solve this conflict

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a small script.
try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.modal-content').hide();
 var selectvalue=$('select').val();
 $('select').click(function(){
   if($('select').val() != selectvalue){
  $('.modal-content').show();
   }
   else{
  $('.modal-content').hide();
   }
 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="choice" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" style="overflow:visible;">
 <optgroup label="Please make a choice">
   <option value="1" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">1st choice</option>
   <option value="2" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">2nd choice</option>
   <option value="3" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">3rd choice</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>




   <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. I've noticed there is conflict somehow because of the selectpicker plugin.

I copy paste a more complete part of the code below (I tried to minimize it earlier to simplify but I might have omit important informations by doing this)

```html
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>


    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">[...]</h4>
          </div>
    <form action="page.php" method="post" target="_top">
          <div class="modal-body">

   <select name="choice" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-primary" style="overflow:visible;">
    <optgroup label="Please make a choice">
       <option value="1" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">1st choice</option>
       <option value="2" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">2nd choice</option>
       <option value="3" data-subtext="Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">3rd choice</option>
    </optgroup>
   </select>  


          </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
           [...]
         </div>
    </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
 
 
 
 
 
 
 <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Large modal</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      ...
    </div>
   </div>
   
  </div>
 </div>
```

I tried to use Vipin's script but I couldn't find a way to solve the conflict.